# Using a Windows XP Batch script read in a list of filenames and then parse filename to create new filenames

Tags: windows, batch, filenames

I have a very old Window XP program that I want to automate a little. It takes three parameters:

```
ITF.EXE <control-file> <input-file> <output-file>
```

and it only accepts 8.3 filenames.

I want to input the filename done_fgx0229.all into the batch script parse to then run the command:

```
ITF.EXE <control-file> fgx0229.all fgx0229.cvs
```

I have a directory with about a hundred files named like:

```
done_fgx0229.all  
done_fgx0330.all
```

etc.

Here is the batch script I am trying to get to work:

```
ECHO ON  
CD C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo  
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
DIR /B done_*.all > ToDo_Files.txt  
set "File=C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo_Files.txt"  
set /a count=0  

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i IN ('Type "%File%"') DO (  
   Set /a count+=1  
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].i=%%i"  
   SET j=  
   SET "j=%i:~6,11%"  
   SET k=  
   SET "k=%i:~6,7%"  
   SET l=  
   SET "l=%i:~9,4%"  

  echo i = %%i, j = %j%, k = %k%, l = %l%  

   Set "FILENAME[!count!].j=%j%"  
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].k=%k%"  
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].l=%l%"  
)

When I run the script here the output for filename done_fgx0229.all

C:\0-Do_Infotran>ECHO ON  
C:\0-Do_Infotran>CD C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo  
C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo>SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo>DIR /B done_*.all  1>ToDo_Files.txt  
C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo>set "File=C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo_Files.txt"  
C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo>set /a count=0  

C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo>FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %i IN ('Type "C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo_Files.txt"') DO (  
Set /a count+=1  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].i=%i"  
 SET j=  
 SET "j=fgx0229.all"  
 SET k=  
 SET "k=fgx0229"  
 SET l=  
 SET "l=0229"  
 echo i = %i, j = fgx0229.all, k = , l =  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].j=fgx0229.all"  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].k="  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].l="  
)  

C:\0-Do_Infotran\ToDo>(  
Set /a count+=1  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].i=done_fgx0229.all"  
 SET j=  
 SET "j=fgx0229.all"  
 SET k=  
 SET "k=fgx0229"  
 SET l=  
 SET "l=0229"  
 echo i = done_fgx0229.all, j = fgx0229.all, k = , l =  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].j=fgx0229.all"  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].k="  
 Set "FILENAME[!count!].l="  
)  
i = done_fgx0229.all, j = fgx0229.all, k = , l =
```

I am not understand why the SET commands for k and l variables do not work. It looks like the strings are getting parsed correctly but the k and l variables are not set.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try:

```py
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

cd /d "c:\0-do_infotran\ToDo"
dir /b done_*.all >.\ToDo_files.txt
set "file=c:\0-do_infotran\ToDo_files.txt"

for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%i in ('type "!file!"')do (

     set /a "count+=1+0" 
     
     set "j=%%~i_%%~j"
     set "k=%%~j"
     set "l=%%~nj.csv"
         
     set "filename_[!count!].j=!j!"
     set "filename_[!count!].k=!k!"
     set "filename_[!count!].l=!l!"
     
     echo\ file = %%~i_%%~j, j = !j!, k = !k!, l = !l!

    )

for /l %%L in (1 1 !count!)do (
      echo\ ITF.EXE !filename_[%%~L].j! !filename_[%%~L].k! !filename_[%%~L].l!
    )

endlocal & goto :eof
```

- For this file list:

```py
done_fgx0221.all
done_fgx0222.all
done_fgx0223.all
done_fgx0224.all
done_fgx0225.all
done_fgx0226.all
done_fgx0227.all
done_fgx0228.all
done_fgx0229.all
done_fgx0210.all
```

- This is the output:

```py
 file = done_fgx0221.all, j = done_fgx0221.all, k = fgx0221.all, l = fgx0221.csv
 file = done_fgx0222.all, j = done_fgx0222.all, k = fgx0222.all, l = fgx0222.csv
 file = done_fgx0223.all, j = done_fgx0223.all, k = fgx0223.all, l = fgx0223.csv
 file = done_fgx0224.all, j = done_fgx0224.all, k = fgx0224.all, l = fgx0224.csv
 file = done_fgx0225.all, j = done_fgx0225.all, k = fgx0225.all, l = fgx0225.csv
 file = done_fgx0226.all, j = done_fgx0226.all, k = fgx0226.all, l = fgx0226.csv
 file = done_fgx0227.all, j = done_fgx0227.all, k = fgx0227.all, l = fgx0227.csv
 file = done_fgx0228.all, j = done_fgx0228.all, k = fgx0228.all, l = fgx0228.csv
 file = done_fgx0229.all, j = done_fgx0229.all, k = fgx0229.all, l = fgx0229.csv
 file = done_fgx0210.all, j = done_fgx0210.all, k = fgx0210.all, l = fgx0210.csv

 ITF.EXE done_fgx0221.all fgx0221.all fgx0221.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0222.all fgx0222.all fgx0222.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0223.all fgx0223.all fgx0223.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0224.all fgx0224.all fgx0224.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0225.all fgx0225.all fgx0225.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0226.all fgx0226.all fgx0226.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0227.all fgx0227.all fgx0227.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0228.all fgx0228.all fgx0228.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0229.all fgx0229.all fgx0229.csv
 ITF.EXE done_fgx0210.all fgx0210.all fgx0210.csv
```

Try to replace: `%j% to !j!, %k% to !k!, %l% to !l!`

```py
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].j=%j%" 
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].k=%k%"
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].l=%l%"
```

You need to use: `!EnableDelayedExpansion!`

```py
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].j=!j!" 
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].k=!k!"
   Set "FILENAME[!count!].l=!l!"
```

---

- ```py
  By default expansion will happen just once, before each line is executed.
  The !delayed! expansion is performed each time the line is executed, or for
  each loop in a FOR looping command.
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

[√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

[√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

[√] **[DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

[√] **[CMD/Bat String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**